# Multiple rows loop in PHP CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, foreach

Please help me to view in PHP (I'm using the CodeIgniter framwork) something like what's shown in image 2.
From the database I select:

- Categ 1 -> Item 1
- Categ 1 -? Item 2
- ......
- Categ 2 -? Item 1
- Categ x -> Item x

One Item can have many Categ.

```
     <div>
          <ul>
             <li>
                <div class="programe-tv_link">
                    <p>Categ 1</p> 
                   <dd> <a href="">>> Item 1</a></dd>
                   <dd> <a href="">>> Item 2</a></dd>
                   <dd> <a href="">>> Item 3</a></dd>
                   <dd> <a href="">>> Item 4</a></dd>
                   <dd> <a href="">>> Item 5</a></dd>
                </div>
                <div class="programe-tv_link">
                    <p>Categ 2</p>
                   <dd> <a href="">>> Item 1</a></dd>
                   <dd> <a href="">>> Item 6</a></dd>
                   <dd> <a href="">>> Item 7</a></dd>
                   <dd> <a href="">>> Item 8</a></dd>
                   <dd> <a href="">>> Item 9</a></dd>
                   <dd> <a href="">>> Item 2</a></dd>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="programe-tv_link">
                    <p>Categ 5</p> 
                   <dd> <a href="">>> Item 1</a></dd>
                   <dd> <a href="">>> Item 2</a></dd>
                   <dd> <a href="">>> Item 3</a></dd>
                </div>
                <div class="programe-tv_link">
                    <p>Categ 4</p>
                   <dd> <a href="">>> Item 1</a></dd>
                </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
    </div>
```

I attach image with illustration. I make view like image 1 where all is selected good only in one `<li>` tag; I need something like IMAGE 2.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My final solution is.

```
    <div id="programe-tv-slide" class="flexslider">
        <strong>Programe TV</strong>
        <div class="redLine"></div>

        <?php $cat_cnl = array(); 
              $list = array(); 
              $i=1;
                 foreach ($category_chaneels as $option) { 
                    $catname = $option['category_name'];
                    $chlname = $option['channel_name'];

                    $cat_cnl[$catname][$i] = $chlname;
                    $list[$i] = $catname;
              $i++;
                 }; 
        ?>
        <?php 
            $rows = array_chunk($cat_cnl, 4, TRUE);
            foreach ($rows as $row) {  //var_dump($rows);
        ?>

          <ul class="slides">    
            <?php
                echo ('<li>');
                foreach ($row as $category => $channels) {
                    echo '<div class="programe-tv_link">'; 
                    echo '<p>' . $category . '</p>'; 
                        foreach ($channels as $channel) {
                                echo '<dd><a href="">' . $channel . '</a></dd> '; 
                        };
                    echo '</div>'; 
                    };      
                echo ('</li>'); 
            ?>
          </ul>
          <?php }; ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that a good way to get the view like image2 is to use some CSS and create a class to all category boxes, setting the width to 30% and floating to allow 3 of them to stay in the same line.

Something like :

```
.class_name {
    width : 31%;
    margin : 0 2% 0 0;
    float : left;
}

.class_name.wrapp {
    width : 33%;
    margin : 0;
}
```

I'm copying this from the [Simpliste](http://cssr.ru/simpliste/) layout, that works realy fine for me.

Comment: Also, I think you will need to use <ul> and <li> only to your category items.

Comment: Hi. Klamir and thx. This not work for me, i use dinamicaly content and i don't know numbers of <li>.